# Tracking error for PHP on ubuntu

Tags: php

I can't track my error of my PHP code in my ubuntu 16. It always give me "**Localhost is unavailable**" whenever my code made some errors. Is it about my compiler? Do I need to install it?

Comment: Did you check your error logs?

Answer (score 0):

Add in your code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

More informations can be found here: [PHP: error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Or if you don't want to show all errors in your page, you are able to check your errors in Apache logs. In Ubuntu they are stored below:

```
/var/log/apache2/
```

File: `error.log`