# Getting a 500 error code while trying to work with the Mailchimp API using PHP and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been trying to work with the Mailchimp API to add contacts to a Mailchimp list. I am using JQuery to process the form and a PHP script to communicate with the Mailchimp API. But I was following the example at: https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/blob/master/README.md

HTML:

```
<form name="SubsribeForm1" id="SubsribeForm1">
  <input name="email" id="emailAdd" type="text" />
  <p class="err"><span id="msg"></span></p>
  <button id="SubscribeEmail">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS code:

```
<script>
    $('#reset-modal').click(function() {
        $('#msg').html("");
    });
    $(document).on("click", "#SubscribeEmail", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var emailAdd = $('input[name="email"]').val();
        console.log(emailAdd);

        $.ajax({
            url: "subscribe.php",
            data: $('#SubsribeForm1').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 15000,
            success: function(response){
                switch(response.status){
                    case 'saved':
                        $('#msg').html(response.message);
                    break;
                    case 'empty':
                        $('#msg').html(response.message);
                    break;
                    default:
                        $('#msg').html(response.message);
                }
             },
             error: function(response){
                $('#msg').html(response.status);
             }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

and subscribe.php:

```
require("_mc.php");

use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;

$MailChimp = new MailChimp('7d446f0db3c6f9e4b5f9b6f35a587fad-us10');
$result = $MailChimp->post('lists/02801ed82a/members', array(
  'email_address'     => $_POST["email"],
  'status'            => 'subscribed'
));

if($result){
    $status = $result["status"];

    if($status == "subscribed"){
        echo "Great! We will keep you updated on our progress.";
    }
    else{
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again.";
    }
}
```

I keep getting a 500 error and am unable to identify the problem here.

Apache error log:

```
[Wed Oct 26 16:09:13.836172 2016] [:error] [pid 11669] [client 185.11.237.250:58101] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'cURL support is required, but can't be found.' in /var/www/html/_mc.php:110\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/_mc.php(48): DrewM\\MailChimp\\MailChimp->makeRequest('post', 'lists/02801ed82...', Array, 10)\n#1 /var/www/html/subscribe.php(11): DrewM\\MailChimp\\MailChimp->post('lists/02801ed82...', Array)\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/_mc.php on line 110, referer: http://meanwise.com/

[Wed Oct 26 16:09:17.195803 2016] [:error] [pid 11667] [client 185.11.237.250:58100] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: email in /var/www/html/subscribe.php on line 9, referer: http://meanwise.com/
[Wed Oct 26 16:09:17.195942 2016] [:error] [pid 11667] [client 185.11.237.250:58100] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'cURL support is required, but can't be found.' in /var/www/html/_mc.php:110\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/_mc.php(48): DrewM\\MailChimp\\MailChimp->makeRequest('post', 'lists/02801ed82...', Array, 10)\n#1 /var/www/html/subscribe.php(11): DrewM\\MailChimp\\MailChimp->post('lists/02801ed82...', Array)\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/_mc.php on line 110, referer: http://meanwise.com/

[Wed Oct 26 16:09:31.813947 2016] [:error] [pid 11668] [client 185.11.237.250:58136] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: email in /var/www/html/subscribe.php on line 9
[Wed Oct 26 16:09:31.814129 2016] [:error] [pid 11668] [client 185.11.237.250:58136] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'cURL support is required, but can't be found.' in /var/www/html/_mc.php:110\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/_mc.php(48): DrewM\\MailChimp\\MailChimp->makeRequest('post', 'lists/02801ed82...', Array, 10)\n#1 /var/www/html/subscribe.php(11): DrewM\\MailChimp\\MailChimp->post('lists/02801ed82...', Array)\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/_mc.php on line 110

[Wed Oct 26 16:09:36.833363 2016] [:error] [pid 31170] [client 185.11.237.250:58140] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: email in /var/www/html/subscribe.php on line 9
[Wed Oct 26 16:09:36.833503 2016] [:error] [pid 31170] [client 185.11.237.250:58140] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'cURL support is required, but can't be found.' in /var/www/html/_mc.php:110\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/_mc.php(48): DrewM\\MailChimp\\MailChimp->makeRequest('post', 'lists/02801ed82...', Array, 10)\n#1 /var/www/html/subscribe.php(11): DrewM\\MailChimp\\MailChimp->post('lists/02801ed82...', Array)\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/_mc.php on line 110
```

After fixing the curl issue, I am getting the following error (I am not a PHP pro):

```
[Thu Oct 27 11:00:54.503907 2016] [:error] [pid 16992] [client 85.53.86.120:64765] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: email in /var/www/html/subscribe.php on line 9, referer: http://meanwise.com/
```

Comment: Did you check Apache error logs? They are stored: `/var/log/apache2/` as `error.log` More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263369/tracking-error-for-php-on-ubuntu/40263395#40263395

Comment: @KarolGasienica I have updated the question with the contents from the error.log file

Comment: have you googled the error message to find a solution? or do you expect us to do that for you?

Comment: @Pete i have googled and tried different solutions like setting up curl. But i still keep getting one error after the another. Been trying to get this to work since yesterday. Isn't Stackoverflow something to ask questions when we run into issues?

Comment: make sure CURL extension enabled or not in php.ini

Comment: ok, now you have fixed your curl issue, you have a new issue which is a totally different question.  Accept the answer that fixed the curl issue and post a new question, refering to this one for context.  But from the looks of your new issue, your post object doesn't have an email index - make sure you post your form - you haven't put a mthod on so it probably will default to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment your server doesn't support curl. To download curl with f.ex. Ubuntu and Apache server:

```
apt-get install php5-curl
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If you are using something like XAMPP uncomment line:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

in `xampp\apache\bin\php.ini` or `xampp\php\php.ini`

And restart your Apache service.

There is no index `email` in your `$_POST` array. Check what it contents with `echo $_POST`, maybe you have made some mistake in spelling.

Comment: Have done that and that error is fixed now. I have updated the question with the current error: "Undefined index: email in /var/www/html/subscribe.php on line 9"

Comment: I think there is an error in your `data` in `AJAX`. Check what contents your `$_POST` array, maybe there is some mistake in spelling? I think CURL problem is now fixed, if you can accept my answer and post new question :) Thanks!